# Is there a typical way of having a view that is a dependent on another?

Tags: mvc

I am working on a program with two views, html and ajax (which will be html transmitted via json).

The HTML view is the standard, and by default the ajax should look the same. However, the ajax view is also meant to have options configurable on the client side for which components of the page should be displayed.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around making an elegant way to handle this requirement. Is there a standard way to handle related views like this?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: While I'm not totally clear on what you are asking, isn't the HTML view a degenerate case of the "ajax" view equivalent to the ajax view with all configurable components turned on?  If so, doesn't that simplify the dependency?

Comment: @psr yes, absolutely. I guess I am just left to a single view with a bunch of conditional statements. It's actually pretty simple if I think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the HTML view just a degenerate case of the "ajax" view -  equivalent to the ajax view with all configurable components turned on? If so, doesn't that simplify the dependency?